# How to the reduce the space between the dots in ToC?

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I want to change the space between the dots in ToC in order to pass from this (an example)

[image: unwanted toc]

To this

[image: wanted toc style]

I have read the `tocloft` package but I can't understand how to do it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should always think of the community when asking a question; please provide a minimal example that we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what your current problem/situation is. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the values of `\cftXdotsep` where `X` represents either `chap`ter, `sec`tion or `subsec`tion:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tocloft}

% \@dotsep = 4.5 default
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{2}
\renewcommand{\cftsecdotsep}{2}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecdotsep}{2}
% ...similar to 
% \renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{2}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}

\end{document}
```

If you want the same dot separation between all ToC entries, just set `\cftdotsep`.

Comment: ! LaTeX Error: Command `\cftdotsep`
 undefined.

Comment: @KcFnMi: Can you provide a minimal example that replicates your current error? I can't when I use my minimal example.